# clickonce deploy, no .manifest file generated

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, deployment, clickonce

I'm stuck at an error when deploying a clickonce package.

It's a c# winform, I followed [this tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/37db1d/deploying-wpf-application-with-clickonce-deployment-techniques/).

> Understanding Deployed Files: For example, I have deployed an
>   application named temp to the my laptop location c:\Test, so I have
>   files like these:
>
> ```
> c:\Temp\setup.exe
> c:\ Temp \publish.htm
> c:\ Temp \ Temp.application
> c:\ Temp \ Temp _1_0_0_0.application
> c:\ Temp \ Temp _1_0_0_0\ Temp.exe.deploy
> c:\ Temp \ Temp _1_0_0_0\ Temp.exe.manifest
> ```
>
> The publish.htm file is present only if we're deploying to a web
>   server. The .manifest and .application files store information about
>   required files, update settings, and other details The .manifest and
>   .application files are digitally signed at the time of publication, so
>   these files can't be modified by hand. If we do make a change,
>   ClickOnce will notice the discrepancy and refuse to install the
>   application. So now our application is ClickOnce application

However when I clicked "publish",

**there's no `.manifest` file generated**.

Thus when I uploaded all these files to my website, the app just cannot find the application update information from my website.

**What caused the problem of not generating `.manifest` file**?